# How do you display the IPv6 NDISC cache in Linux?

Tags: linux, ipv6, iproute2, ndp

Suppose you've configured IPv6 proxy NDP on one of your Linux systems like so:

```
ip -6 neighbor add proxy 2001:db8:1234::5 dev eth1
```

How do you verify that the configuration took? `ip -6 neighbor show` doesn't appear to show proxy entries and `ip -6 neighbor show proxy` isn't a supported command.

Comment: Maybe `ip -6 neighbor show nud all`?

Comment: That shows more addresses (e.g. `:: dev lo`) but not the proxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the ip tool just doesn't print the NTF_PROXY flag. In ip/ipneigh.c, after the NTF_ROUTER block, try adding

```
   if (r->ndm_flags & NTF_PROXY) {
            fprintf(fp, " proxy");
    }
```

I don't have an NDP proxy installation, so I can't test it. From reading the kernel sources, however, it appears that the entries will all get returned and the flag should be set for proxy entries.

Comment: That didn't work, unfortunately. I also tried adding "fprintf(fp, " flags: %02x\n", r->ndm_flags);" to the beginning of print_neigh and none of the entries had the NTF_PROXY flag set.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried ip ntable ?

Comment: It gives me lots of useful information about the NDISC cache, but not the entries themselves. I'm beginning to think these are write-only values, at least for my kernel version.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness:

```
 shell> ip -6 neigh del proxy 2001:db8:1234::1234:5678 dev eth1
 shell> ip -6 maddr show dev eth1                      
 3:      eth1
         inet6 ff02::1:ff34:5678
 ...
```

It's just the last 6 nibbles but that's often all you need.